# How could use external repository with GitLab runner?

Tags: gitlab

I have two project in my GitLab.
For one is backend(Golang)
Another is Frontend(Vue.js)

I want to trigger the CI with backend and frontend when update the bakend code.
So I have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` in backend project like this

```
stages:
  - backendCI
  - frontendCI

backendCI:
  image: golang:latest
  stage: backendCI
  script:
    - make all

frontendCI:
  image: node:latest
  stage: frontendCI
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build 

  dependencies:
    - repository: sw/frontend
      on: develop
```

But there have a error :

> Error: jobs:frontend dependencies should be an array of strings

I don't know how can I use frontend repository in backend runner.

Answer (score 0):

The error means the yaml file is invalid. You misunderstood the usage of `dependencies` which only refer to a previous job to fetch artifacts from it.

If I understand well your case, you have 2 separate repositories so you can have 2 separate `.gitlab-ci.yml` and you can easily trigger another pipeline using the [API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html#triggering-multi-project-pipelines-through-api) :

```
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" \ 
"https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/ID/pipeline?ref=develop"
```

Make that call in `.gitlab-ci.yml` of your backend refering the frontend project (replace the ID in the url with the id of frontend project)

If you are Gitlab Premium ( version >= 11.8), there is a native [syntax](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html#creating-multi-project-pipelines-from-gitlab-ciyml) to trigger cross-project pipelines.